# Read different variables from a file [java] and put them into a JList

Tags: java, jlist, java-6

I have some difficulties writing a code wich should be able to read heterogeneous features from a .txt file.
This is a sample file:

> size=1.523763e-13 Type= aBc, KCd, EIf

I need to find this features and then put them in a Jlist on netbeans.

To find the size variable I've thought to use the BufferedReader class, but I don't know what to do next!

Any help?
My code by far:

```
public String findSize() {
    String spec = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null) {
            if (line.contains("size")) {
                for(int i = line.indexOf("size")+1, i = line.length(), i++)
                    spec +=...;
```

Comment: Please show what your have tried till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily by splitting the string you read via `BufferedReader` or `Scanner`.

In the below example I have used `Scanner` and am reading the lines from `System.in`. You can replace it to read the lines from your source file.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> typeString;
    while(in.hasNext()) {
        String[] str = in.nextLine().split("=");
        System.out.println("Size: " + str[1].split(" ")[0] + " Type: " + str[2]);
        typeString = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str[2].split(", ")));
    }
}
```

Please note that this is just for demonstration purpose. You can split the String and play with the sub-strings and store them anyway you want.

Input:

```
size=1.523763e-13 Type=aBc, KCd, EIf
```

Output:

```
Size: 1.523763e-13 Type: aBc, KCd, EIf

typeString --> {aBc, KCd, EIf}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! If I would insert all the types in a JList, what should I do?